# I've lost my edit privileges, How can I get it back?

Tags: discussion, edits

I was trying to delete my question because other users have downvoted my question, but **it has answers** and one of them is also accepted, thats why **I can't delete** my question.

Finally I decided to edit my question in such a manner that it may get a moderator's attention for possible deletion. Now **I cant edit other posts**.

I am really sorry and I assure you all that it won't happen again, but please give me my edit privileges back.
Thanks.

Comment: If you want a moderator to look at your post, flag it. Don't vandalize it.

Comment: But I didn't knew it before I made the mistake

Comment: Well, now you know. Don't do it again. Your edit privilege is completely unrelated to that AFAIK. It's based on rejected suggestions. Don't mix the two things.

Comment: Yaa I wont do that again. But what about edit ban ?

Comment: You won't understand how the edit ban works unless you actually read what people are telling you. Myself, Bart and hims056 have already told you why you got that ban. The post linked in my first comment also contains that information.

Comment: Will I get my edit privileges after 7 days, or is this ban for forever ?

Comment: Why would the FAQ say it's a 7 day ban if it was an infinite ban?

Comment: Deepak, are you and @Freedom friends/relatives or something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You didn't lose your edit privilege because of that downvoted question. You lose your it because of your too many [rejected edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2182868). You have suggested 10 edits and 7 of them are rejected. So you are temporary banned (for a week) from suggesting edits. So you can suggest edits after a week. But remember suggest good and useful edits.

Comment: I know, It is not true. Because I didn't suggested too many edits, then why ?

Comment: @StarGazer - edit ban doesn't depend on number of suggestion but it depends on approved - rejected suggested edits ratio. Your edit ratio was 3:7 at the time of ban.

Comment: @StarGazer Too many of your suggested edits were rejected, indicating that you don't do a good enough job editing. You can now no longer suggest edits for a week. Go through [your suggested edits](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2273202/deepak?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) and try to understand why they were rejected.

Comment: So I've got a suspension period of 7 days, right ? Are you sure

Comment: @StarGazer - You are saying you lost your edit privilege. So it's temporary ban from suggesting edits. It is not a suspension.